# How can we set up Maven project in GoCD?

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, go-cd

I have worked with Jenkins before. But we moved to GoCD now. I want to run a simple Maven project periodically for regression testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per their [support forum](https://support.thoughtworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/213254306-Using-Maven-with-Go):

> You can use maven and Go together by using the "exec" builder of cruise.
>
> Please do the following to set up maven with Go:
>
> 1. Create a batch file(If you are on windows, else, .sh file) with the maven command you want to run through Go.
> 2. While setting up the pipeline, choose "exec" as your builder and give the batch file name (created in step 1) and the parameters, if any.
>
> Go recognizes build tools like ant, rake and nant; any other build tool can be integrated with cruise using the "exec" builder where you call the build commands through a batch file.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Maven Task Plugin](https://github.com/ruckc/gocd-maven-plugin) for GoCD.

Checkout the GoCD plugins overview: https://www.gocd.org/plugins/#task

To install a plugin, copy the JAR file to `<server installation directory>/plugins/external` then restart the GoCD server.

Comment: Looks like the plugin is not working with newer GoCD versions.